# Storage issue in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have 6 site collection each site collection has 200000MB now one of the site collection is reached to 198980MB can anyone suggest how to increase the space for this site collection or is there any option very urgent

Comment: Have you set a quota for your site collection or collections on Central Administraion > Application Management > Configure quotas and locks?

Answer (score 0):

To configure the site collection quota, create a new quota template and choose it as the current quota template for your site collection. This can be done on **Central Administration** > **Application Management** with **Specify quota templates** and **Configure quotas and locks**.

For further explanation, refer to TechNet article [Create, edit, and delete quota templates in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263223.aspx).